# Visual Studio Setup project set install location

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-setup-proje, visual-studio-setup

I am using visual studio setup project extension for build setup package for my application. I have removed the `Install Location Select Interface` and instead application should be installed to the location i have preset. At the moment application install location is set by `Right-click` on `Application` Folder in `File system` UI and set the `DefaultLocation` value as `[ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer]\[ProductName]`. It is installing to `ProgramFiles(X86)` folder.

I want to install the application inside `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` folder. Is there anyone who knows how to set this folder structure as a default value.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In a Visual Studio Setup project, you control the default install path by setting the DefaultLocation property of the Application Folder folder, within the File System Editor.

This, in turn, as you've found, defaults to [ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer][ProductName]. You can either replace this property entirely (you should keep [ProgramFilesFolder], at the very least though), or you can modify these properties.

[ProgramFilesFolder] is built in, and correctly leads to the Program Files directory on the target machine, no matter how customized the setup of Window is. The other two properties are properties of the setup project (select the Setup project in Solution Explorer, and examine the properties grid to find them). These default to the company name you supplied when installing Visual Studio, and the name of the Setup project.

Comment: I need to install my application to the location `C:\Windows\SysWOW64` not inside `programfiles`

Comment: You might try [WindowsVolume][SysWOW64], but I'm not sure it will work. Here's the documentation for the standard installer properties. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370905(v=vs.85).aspx#system_folder_properties

Comment: as doc said , [WindowsVolume][WindowsFolder][SysWOW64] is equal to c:\windows\SysWOW64

Comment: Thank You for the Information and reference link you provided. I have go through the documentation and found the correct answer. It should be like this `[SystemFolder][Manufacturer]\[ProductName]`