# VS 2017 Setup Project wouldn't install in C:\DestFolder\

Tags: visual-studio-2017, setup-project

Due to the administrative privilege of the application, I need to install my program including `.exe` and `.dll` in `C:\DestFolder\SubFolder\` but I keep getting `C:\Program Files\\[Manufacturer]\\[Product Name]\` where the placeholders are specified in the properties window.

I tried [this article](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/acaa2bcf-4f45-445f-af2d-7504e9cdd6a0/visual-c-setup-project-how-do-i-create-a-folder-when-installing?forum=winformssetup)) but no good.

Please don't give me answer like try changing the defaultlocation to `C:\Destination\` of the Application Folder as I have already tried. Also I don't want solution like just change the installation destination path manually during the installation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the answer from this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36910565/visual-studio-setup-project-set-install-location):

"[ProgramFilesFolder] is built in, and correctly leads to the Program Files directory on the target machine, no matter how customized the setup of Window is..."

There might be tools out there that allow installing outside of Program Files.

[Edit] Infact I've found out this great extension for VS 2017 community called Wix. There's a guy who did a fabulous [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-wyUxQux7xY) on it.

Comment: It's not clear how the question "how to install to C:\Destfolder" is answered by "I found out how to install to the Program Files folder".

Comment: The answer doesn't say I found out how to install to the Program Files folder. It explains how to install to C:\Destfolder.